# Replacing shorter with longers instructions in-place (assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, opcode

When replacing a longer instruction with a shorter one, we can just pad with `nop`s.

How would I do an inline replace of an the other way around?

And by **inline** I mean not a `jmp` to some other free memory and then getting back.

Said with other words, is it possible to somehow **insert** more ops? How is that done? Should the header of the binary be modified somehow? What happens with all the `jmp` ops (will they keep working after that theoretical change?). What about if there are absolute `jmp`s? Those should be modified as well, right? What else should be done (if this is actually possible)?

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: That shouldn't matter as the question is theoretical, but I used https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/ to get those opcodes.

Comment: I have written code to do exactly this in the past, but it was rather complicated as I had to write a basic opcode dissasembler to identify and fix references. I approached it a little differently though, instead of adding instructions, I allocated more ram, copied out the assembler that would be overwritten by a long jump instruction, and then updated all the references in my copied assembler so it could be executed from the new location (on the fly PIC). The jump was pointed to my new method, which then could inherit the old method's code by jumping to the modified assembler I had copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in play here:

All types of simple jumps, whether conditional (`je`, `jne`, and so on) or unconditional (`jmp`), exist in two forms, short and near, where the former has a signed byte-sized offset (range -128 to +127) and the latter has a signed dword-sized offset (range -2147483648 to +2147483647).

Changing the condition on a conditional jump does not require a change in jump size, but changing the target address of the jump might if the desired target address is out of range.

If you wanted to actually change the target of a jump to a new location, which is out of range of the type of jump currently there, or insert more instructions at the code site, you would need to relocate the code that comes after it.

As you suspect, doing this involves fixing up all relative references that straddle the new gap in the code and also any absolute references that follow the gap, and if what's being referenced is relocated as well, also the absolute references that come before the gap.

The difficulty of such an operation goes from moderately complex to impossible, depending on how well-structured the code is and what information you have available.

If the code in question was emitted by a compiler and you have symbol information available, it can be done, otherwise it is usually very difficult, unless the changes required are very small.

Comment: That answers my initial question (and confirms my fears). Btw, do you happen to know if IDA Pro handles this properly? How do they do it?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `handles`. I've used IDA Pro as a disassembler only - I am vaguely aware that it has some patching capabilities but I haven't used them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have machine instructions

```
A; B; C; D; E;
```

and need to replace B with a larger X, then you can remove C,D, etc. to make enough space for a jump.

Say `C; D;` is big enough. So you end up with

```
A; jmp freeSpace; back: E 
... 
<previous end of binary> 
freeSpace: X; C; D; jmp back;
```

This varies a bit if C and/or D are themselves jumps. But you can always make it work.

Back in the day I used this to patch a binary where only a paper assembly listing was available. Not elegant, but works fine. Wouldn't be a bit surprised if this is what Ida Pro does.

Comment: Indeed, I was aware of that solution. That should be way less difficult, but it does feel kind of hacky.